# Saving an Exchange Mail in a normal filesystem folder using ews

Tags: .net, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I need to fetch some emails from an exchange server via exchange web services managed api and save them as .msg files in a regular folder on a filesystem. Not an exchange folder.
Does somebody know how i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I used "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" to create the msg files.

Comment: Luke, can you say how you used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook to create msg files using EWS???